# Why does my Drag-and-Drop operation fail from RecyclerView?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

**My overall goal is to be able of dragging a row from the RecyclerView to another view inside my app.**

With a standard RecyclerView with LinearLayoutmanager and no extra mumbo-jumbo my drag-and-drop operations work flawlessly. However, as soon as I introduce a custom library called [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) to make each row swipeable to reveal extra actions everything fails and I get the common error:

```
08-28 09:59:03.465: I/ViewRootImpl(15310): Reporting drop result: false
```

Also I can see that the only DragEvents that are fired on my receiving view are `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` and `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED`, all other events are skipped. As you can see I am returning `true` from `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` but that doesn't help, my thought is that the custom library somehow eats my event. But I can't pinpoint where.

Here is my OnDragListener:

```
private class MyDropListener implements View.OnDragListener {

  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    // Doing some calculations based on event x and y. Not related to the problem.

    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // Some unrelated code, updating how views are displayed
        return true;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
        // Some unrelated code, updating how views are displayed
        return true;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Some unrelated code, updating some data and updating how views are displayed
        return true;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        // Some unrelated code, updating how views are displayed
        return true;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        // Some unrelated code, updating how views are displayed
        return true;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        // Some unrelated code, updating how views are displayed
        return true;

      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've experimented now for a few days inside the library but can't find a solid solution exactly where my event dies. Sometimes I've managed to get the drop working, but it's very irregular behaviour.

I've also made a Github issue for this problem:

[AndroidSwipeLayout - issue #211](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/issues/211)

I'm sure this is not specific to this library, but a problem when there's too much gesture detection going on for each view in a list. The library is really excellent I think and I don't wish to write that interaction myself.

Any thoughts, or comments, are welcome and appreciated. Even if you don't know the exact solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually not caused by the library, or the listeners, it was caused by an EditText that was located in the same layout.

It was solved by creating a new class that subclasses EditText and ignores the dragEvent.

```
public class EditTextNoDrag extends EditText {

  public EditTextNoDrag(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public EditTextNoDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public EditTextNoDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) { 
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  public EditTextNoDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        return false;
      default:
        return super.onDragEvent(event);
    }
  }
}
```

You can also toggle the focusable of the EditText on and off.
See this related isseu: [Prevent drag drop of custom mimetype to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041523/prevent-drag-drop-of-custom-mimetype-to-edittext)